# Is there a way to make local titles using subplot2grid in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm using suplot2grid like in the example in the matplotlib page:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=3)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,0), colspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1, 2), rowspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2, 0))
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2, 1))
plt.suptitle("subplot2grid")
```

[image]

Is there a way to make a local subtitle below ax1, instead of the global one on top of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can add titles to each sub plot using the set_title() method of the axes. Each title will still be display above the axis. If you want text below the axis, you could use set_xlabel. For example:

```
import pylab as plt
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (0,0), colspan=3)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1,0), colspan=2)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (1, 2), rowspan=2)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2, 0))
ax5 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3), (2, 1))

# add titles to subplots
ax2.set_title('plot 2')
ax3.set_title('plot 3')

# add x-label to subplot
ax1.set_xlabel('plot 1 x-label')

# add y-label to subplot
ax1.set_ylabel('y-label')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also use figtext to add a new title like this:

```
# add Text
pos = ax1.get_position()
x = pos.x0 + 0.35
y = pos.y0
plt.figtext(x,y,'new title')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: For completeness, you should add a `set_ylabel` ;)

Comment: Yup, I know, but I want another global subtitle that encompases the plots under ax1, not a specific plot for each new plot.

Comment: In that case, I think you'll have to add text directly. See my edit.

Comment: @Leonpalafox note `plt.suptitle` really just calls `gcf().suptitle()` which is a figure level title.  An out of band solution is to just do this as two figures and composite them where ever you are going to end up using this.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might be some command to manage to do this